# wordpress - advance custom fields export content

Tags: import, wordpress, export, advanced-custom-fields

Is it possible export the data of advance custom fields saved in the pages of another wordpress installation?

basically, I would like to import this data into my new wp installation, since they have the same contents.

I found the option to export from acf, but it seems to export only the structure of custom fields but not the content.

is it possible? any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: Go to `Tools > Export`, select `Fields` and click `Download Export file`. https://i.imgur.com/7RU7VYE.png

Answer (score 0):

The data can be exported from the wp_postmeta table in your database. If you're using multisite, the adjust your export for the corresponding table prefix, e.g. wp_2_postmeta.